# weird php array syntax errors

Tags: php

I have:
on my pc:wamp server (apache+php-5.4.3+mysql)
on my vps:nginx+php5-fpm+mysql(all latest in the ubuntu 64 bit server repository).

recently I have reinstalled the whole vps

my problem is,

statement like this:

```
function foo($arr){

return $arr;

}


foo(['foo1','foo2','foo3'])
```

works on my pc, and used to work on the server (same installation) but now it gives
an error such as:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/Websites/Domains/squazza/php/db.php 
on line 261
```

(replacing the [  ] with Array( ) does fix the problem)

now I assume that this problem is related to php.ini so i am asking what setting could possibly be affecting this kind of behavior and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) that short syntax is only avaible in php 5.4+ I suspect your php versions are different.

This [list](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of new features in PHP5.4 maybe of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using PHP 5.4. Run `phpinfo()` in your script and check it. And remember, you can have different PHP version in CLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @piddl0r, the short array syntax (`[ 1, 2, 3 ]`) was added in PHP 5.4. You'll note from [The Ubuntu Package Archive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) that [Ubuntu 12.04 - Precise Pangolin - only provided PHP 5.3.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&keywords=php5); [PHP 5.4.6 was provided in the next release, Quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=quantal&keywords=php5). To check your version of PHP, use `phpinfo()` or `php --version` on the command line.